# Node/jsonwebtoken- jwt.sign() does not add in payload to my token

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm building an API in Node and I've set up `const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')` to use JWTs. The problem is the token that is generated does not include the payload in it. I've tried decoding it using `express-jwt` and `jsonwebtoken.verify()`.

When I decode on JWT.io using the secret/public keys, signature is verified and all token details are correct, but there is no payload.

Here is my code.

user.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const { secretKey } = require("../keyConfig")
const createToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, secretKey, {
    algorithm: "RS256",
    expiresIn: 12000,
    subject: "Login details",
  })
}

const token = createToken(user)
```

authMiddleware.js

```
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt")
const js = require('jsonwebtoken')

const getTokenFromHeader = (req) => {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
  ) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    const de = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())
    const ver = js.verify(token, publicKey)
    return token
  }
}

const checkIfAuth = jwt({
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
  secret: publicKey,
  getToken: getTokenFromHeader,
})
```

I recreated the error by building a new project. Repeated the code above and had the same issue. Token is created, all details are correct but no payload.

Here is the decoded token:

`{ "iat": 1668995400, "exp": 1669007400, "sub": "Login Details" }`

Comment: What do you mean by payload in this case? What do you expect to be in the JWT?

Comment: @Sandsten `{ id: user.id }` is the payload.

Comment: Are you sure that `user.id` isn't `undefined`? if it's `undefined` it won't be added as payload.

Comment: @Sandsten I've tried hardcoding the id value and the same issue.

Comment: Where do you try to read the payload? You can try jwt.decode(token) in users.js just to see if it has the payload there. If it has the payload there the token is correct there at least. You can also use this website to see the decoded JWT https://jwt.io/

Comment: @Sandsten you were right. I had a typo. The payload was undefined so it was not being added in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are using the authMiddleware.js in your question. But when I add a middleware in express doing the same thing and making a request from postman it all works fine.

Maybe you can use this to figure out why your code doesn't work.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const SECRET = "qwerty";

const token = jwt.sign({ id: 1234 }, SECRET);

// Copy the value and use in postman
console.log(token);

// Middleware
const getTokenFromHeader = (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
  ) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const de = JSON.parse(
      Buffer.from(token.split(".")[1], "base64").toString()
    );
    // verify is asyncronous
    jwt.verify(token, SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        next();
      }
      res.tokenPayload = decoded;
    });
  }
  next();
};
app.use(getTokenFromHeader);

app.get("/test-token", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(res.tokenPayload);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

[image: request]